# Elastic Search Java API for Search Templates

Tags: elasticsearch

As per the elastic document, There is a REST API to add mustache templates (Search Template)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-template.html

does Java API support this now? If yes, What is the syntax to create search templates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it does.

here is the documentation.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-template.html

hope that helps.